# JPA .find() mutates instance

Tags: hibernate, jpa, find

I didn't expect this.

I have simple JPA Entity:

```
@Entity
@Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "getShredInfoByDocUUID",
                query = "SELECT I FROM DocShreddingExtension I WHERE " +
                        "I.document2.UUID = :uuid"
        )
})
@EntityListeners({
        ShreddingListener.class,
})
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id",
        scope = DocShreddingExtension.class
)
public class DocShreddingExtension implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "code")
    private ShreddingType shreddingType;


    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "uuid")
    private Document2 document2;

    public DocShreddingExtension() {
    }

    public DocShreddingExtension(Document2 doc, ShreddingType type) {
        this();
        this.document2 = doc;
        this.shreddingType = type;
    }

    public ShreddingType getShreddingType() {
        return shreddingType;
    }

    public void setShreddingType(ShreddingType shreddingType) {
        this.shreddingType = shreddingType;
    }

    public Document2 getDocument2() {
        return document2;
    }

    public void setDocument2(Document2 document2) {
        this.document2 = document2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        DocShreddingExtension that = (DocShreddingExtension) o;
        return Objects.equals(shreddingType, that.shreddingType) &&
                Objects.equals(document2, that.document2);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(shreddingType, document2);
    }
}
```

and the DAO upsert method:

```
public void upsert(DocShreddingExtension shreddingInfo) {
        DocShreddingExtension saved = entityManager.find(DocShreddingExtension.class, shreddingInfo);

        if (saved == null)
            entityManager.persist(shreddingInfo);
        else
            entityManager.merge(shreddingInfo);
    }
```

Document2 model class:

```
@Table(name = "document")
@Entity
@Audited
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,
        scope = Document2.class
)
public class Document2 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "doc_uuid")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String UUID;

    @Column(name = "extId")
    private String extId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "documentType")
    private DocType docType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document2", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<DocVersion> docVersions;

    @Column(name = "entityState")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EDocState eDocState;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "party_id")
    private PartyKind partyContainer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rootDoc", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<RelatedDoc> relatedDocs;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "product_instance", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "doc_uuid"))
    @Column(name = "productInstance")
    private List<String> productInstanceIds;

    public int change;

    public Document2() {
        this.docVersions = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUUID() {
        return UUID;
    }

    public void setUUID(String UUID) {
        this.UUID = UUID;
    }

    public String getExtId() {
        return extId;
    }

    public void setExtId(String extId) {
        this.extId = extId;
    }

    public DocType getDocType() {
        return docType;
    }

    public void setDocType(DocType docType) {
        this.docType = docType;
    }

    public Set<DocVersion> getDocVersions() {
        return docVersions;
    }

    public void setDocVersions(Set<DocVersion> docVersions) {
        this.docVersions = docVersions;
    }

    public EDocState geteDocState() {
        return eDocState;
    }

    public void seteDocState(EDocState eDocState) {
        this.eDocState = eDocState;
    }

    public void addDocVersion(DocVersion version) {
        this.docVersions.add(version);
    }

    public PartyKind getPartyContainer() {
        return partyContainer;
    }

    public void setPartyContainer(PartyKind partyContainer) {
        this.partyContainer = partyContainer;
    }

    public List<RelatedDoc> getRelatedDocs() {
        return relatedDocs;
    }

    public void setRelatedDocs(List<RelatedDoc> relatedDocs) {
        this.relatedDocs = relatedDocs;
    }

    public List<String> getProductInstanceIds() {
        return productInstanceIds;
    }

    public void setProductInstanceIds(List<String> productInstanceIds) {
        this.productInstanceIds = productInstanceIds;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Document2 document2 = (Document2) o;
        return Objects.equals(UUID, document2.UUID);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(UUID);
    }
}
```

my intention with this was to check if the entity exists in the database already and based on that either save or merge it.

what happens is that instance is being found so 'saved' is set but 'shreddingInfo' changes changes to the 'saved' instance meanwhile so when I call .merge() there is nothing to be merged.

Question is why does entity manager changes a parameter in the .find() method? 
I suppose this is not intended.

Answer (score 0):

The find method expects the primary key as second parameter. 
But you passed the entity!

That leads to this unexpected behavior.

Your mapping is not correct you must use @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn when you have a shared primary key:

```
public class DocShreddingExtension implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String uuid;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "code")
    private ShreddingType shreddingType;


    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Document2 document2;

}
```

Now you can call find with the uuid.

Find some more infos here:
http://websystique.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-unidirectional-with-shared-primary-key-annotation-example/

Comment: well, you might be right that I provided wrong parameter, but as you can see my entity has object (another entity) as for @Id. 
So I should have done what you written, but with that I get:

`WARNING: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.nws.vedica.model.entity.DocShreddingExtension. Expected: class com.nws.vedica.model.entity.DocShreddingExtension`

Comment: Can you post the whole code of DocShreddingExtension with all annotations?

Comment: And the Document2 too please

Comment: there it is! i have excluded named queries (there's too much of them) but that should not matter

Comment: Oh I see. You have no ID Class for DocShreddingExtension. I will update my answer

Comment: not good. now I have two fields in 'docshreddingextension' table: uuid[pk](varchar) and code(bigint). 
On find() I get error:
`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
WARNING: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

Comment: how does the generated sql looks like?

Comment: it looks overcomplicated. like, i can implement this with providing extension-entity the unique id but I liked my initial approach that was very simple..